# Make iOs VoiceOver spell out abbreviated "W" as "Watt"

Tags: ios, uiwebview, accessibility, voiceover

I'm adding accessibility support to an app where one part of the app is a UIWebView with text information. 
The text contains abbreviated units such as W for watt, lm for lumen, etc...

The VoiceOver functionality does not by it self recognize the letter W as watt (of course it is hard) and it needs some help.

I know about the html tags  and  (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp)

Eg.

```
15 <ABBR title='Watt'>W</ABBR><br>
15 <ACRONYM title='Watt'>W</ACRONYM><br>
```

Unfortunately they are not recognized by the VoiceOver system.

Does anybody know a way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test to see if voiceover is active with

```
BOOL UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning();
```

If it is active write out the html with watt instead of w. As a blind user I question weather expanding the abreviation to a full word is necessary. I ahve no problems with abbreviations like mm, m, and kmf or distance. I assume anyone using the app can tell based on your apps function and context that w is watt.

Answer (score 8):

```
<span role="text" aria-label="Watt">W</span>;
```

Comment: Consider adding a comment to your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on a UIWebView on iOS7 when I tested.  However, you can either switch to using a <div> or wrap it with an additional span: <span role=text" aria=label="watt"><span aria-hidden="true">W</span></span>. This is because the <span> will only use the aria-label if there is no direct text node descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Spell out Watt, but make "att" the same color as the background text. Or if you can select which parts should be read out loud, write the text again somewhere else (hidden) but with "Watt" in it instead and read that instead.

Comment: I've thought about a solution like this but I don't like the idea, its more like a hack.